# How to attach UserDetails to Principal received from JWT token using Spring Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have these services

- oauth2 authentication server that uses JDBC provider (DB-1)
- Zuul-enabled web application that proxies requests to authserver and resource server
- resource that enables @EnableOauth2Resource (DB-2)

I need to fetch the User Details in resource server from DB-2 using credentials received from DB-1 and set enabled authorities to the current Principal for further using with @PreAuthorize of @RolesAllowed annotations.

Are there some hook to replace or update org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication after successful authentication using oauth2 token?

Answer (score 3):

I got the principal at resource server by configuring my Resource Server as..

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    public ResourceServerConfiguration() {
        super();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    /* returns org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService */
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService () {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserAuthenticationConverter userAuthenticationConverter () {
        DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter defaultUAC = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
        defaultUAC.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService());
        return defaultUAC;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        DefaultAccessTokenConverter defaultATC = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        defaultATC.setUserTokenConverter(userAuthenticationConverter());
        return defaultATC;
    }

    @Bean
    RemoteTokenServices getRemoteTokenServices () {
        RemoteTokenServices rts = new RemoteTokenServices();
rts.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/check_token");
        rts.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
        rts.setClientId("yourClientID");
        rts.setClientSecret("yourClientSecret");
        return rts;
    }
    ...

}
```

basically here we are updating the authentication principal at resource server with customUserDetailsService by getting the authentication info from accesstoken. RemoteTokenServices queries the `/check_token` endpoint of auth-server to obtain the contents of an access token. If the endpoint returns a 400 response, this indicates that the token is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

If using Spring Boot and your user details can be fetched in a standard way, first check the Spring Boot documentation on [customizing user information](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-custom-user-info).

If you need further control, I suggest providing a ResourceServerConfigurer to provide a custom [ResourceServerTokenServices](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/ResourceServerTokenServices.html) which can populate your OAuth2Authentication with the principal details you require.

The ResourceServerTokenServices is handed an accessToken by the OAuth2AuthenticationManager or the OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter and expects a populated OAuth2Authentication in return.  This provides your the opportunity to fetch principal information and stuff it into the OAuth2Authentication object.

Again, if using Spring Boot, the ResourceServerConfigurer, if instantiated as a bean, will be picked up by the OAuth2 auto configuration and your ResourceServerTokenServices will be registered.

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);
    }
}
```

override

```
@Override
public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessToken) {
    // fetch user information and return populated authentication
}
```